# Getting CURRENT path to own executable (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, path

Everything on StackOverflow says to use a bunch of different methods to get the full path to your executable. The PROBLEM is that NONE of these methods get the path to your executable. They get the path to where your executable WAS when it was executed. If you run the executable and then move it, the path that you get is ALWAYS the path you ran it from. How can I get the path to where it actually is?

Comment: Why are you moving the executable? What is the real problem you're trying to solve? What platform is this for since any answer will have to be platform specific.

Comment: Linux? Windows? Android? Mac OS-X? MS-DOS?  VMS/CMS? PDP-10? Surely you don't believe that this is something that works identically in every operating system in the world, which ever existed, or which will ever exist?

Comment: At least in Windows you can't move an executable while there's a process running it.

Comment: Why am I moving it? That totally doesn't matter. What's the "real" issue?! The one listed above... I can't make it more clear than that. For the guy who gave a sarcastic comment, go away. You, being arrogant and not seeing that I obviously mean Windows, does not help. For the guy who said you can't move an executable while it's running: Yes you can.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: apparently you're wrong (just did it) on Win10

Comment: @engf-010 At least on Win7 as well

Comment: @engf-010: Thanks for correcting me & testing. I mistakenly thought I *knew*. Now I will have to find a solution and reopen this question, grumble grumble...

Comment: Please fix the wording of the question. Stack Overflow is not a forum, where this language may be tolerated. Since you ignored it when it was offered to you, please take the [tour] now. Also visit the [help].

Comment: Exe files are mapped into memory as NT sections and the kernel knows which file this is because it has a reference to it so it can read from it but I don't think you can tell from user-mode.

Comment: I've confirmed that `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` returns the current path, sans the drive designator, on the current device, when the running executable is moved within that device. When I move it with `move` command to another device the command succeeds but the file is just copied. Voted to **reopen**. My test code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb875cd35807634c

Comment: @IInspectable: I rolled back the edit with the emotional plea. I think that's a good way to deal with such.

Comment: Please include information on which *"different methods"* you tried, that didn't exhibit the desired behavior. You can link to other Q&A's, or outline the respective procedures. Since you are new here, this may not be immediately obvious: *You* are required to put in effort to produce a good question.

Answer (score 1):

`GetFileInformationByHandleEx` with option `FileNameInfo` returns the current path, sans the drive designator, on the current device, when the running executable is moved within that device. To use this you apparently need to have opened the file for reading at program start up (before it's moved). To get the executable's path at startup you can use `GetModuleFileName`.